# How do I show the div where I want it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button. When I press this button, the div element that I hide is displayed on the first page, but when I click on that button again, it opens again on the top page. I want it to be shown on the following pages

I think I need to do something for my project, can you help me?

```js
function test1() {
  document.getElementById("sign").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("sign").style.opacity = "1";
}

function test11() {
  document.getElementById("sign").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("sign").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("sign").style.transition = "all 2s";
}
```

```css
#sign {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 35vw;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="kapsayici">
  <div class="üst">
    <h4>PYTHON</h4>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Python Nedir ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nerelerde Kullanılır ?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kurulum</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="test1()">Kayıt Ol</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Giriş Yap</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <video loop muted autoplay>
      <source src="media/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="media/main.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <div class="main_text">
      <h1>ASLA HAYALİNDEN VAZGEÇME</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="python_nedir">
  </div>
  <div id="sign">
    <img src="img/x_sign.png" onclick="test11()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u do a working snippet to illustrate the issue?

Comment: I am sorry to tell you but this question cannot be answered the way it is written - because it is not clear what you are trying to communicate. What do you mean by "the first page" and "on the following pages"? Is each page a separate html file? In your code, which element is the button you are pushing? Is that ALL your css? It is nowhere near enough. Please fix your question.